# Replace part of string in excel formulas using VBA array

Tags: arrays, excel, replace

I have a worksheet named Evaluation in excel which contains a formula like **"=SUM('Production-2020'!A1:A12)"**, this formula adds the production values of a sheet named **Production-2020**. Every year I create another production sheet like **Production-2021**, *Production-2022* etc. what I want, when I change the year in Evaluation, I want the formula like "**=SUM('Production-2020'!A1:A12)**" to be replaced with =SUM('Production-2021'!A1:A12) or with any selected year. I dont want to practise INDIRECT function due to its volatility as I have so many formulae up to thousands and will slow down my work. also the normal replace function in VBA works fine but it takes long time up to 2 minutes to replace all formulae from current year to new selected year. Is there any way I can do to replace in less than a second?

Comment: Any reason to have each year on a separate sheet? Best would be to have all data on one sheet - with an additional year column. Then you can filter by year.

Comment: @Ike, Each year has different data structure so I separate them in different sheets to avoid confusion.

Comment: then it might make sense to merge the relevant data via powerquery